# It looks like the implementationof __DEV__ has changed. Update -[RCTBatchedBridge loadSource:]

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

When I try and prepare my react native app to run on a device that app terminates with the following error which I can't figure out. I have read that node needs to be version +4 but I am running 4.1.2 so I don't think thats it. Any ideas?

```
TutorMeNow[81429:1527409] *** Assertion failure in __31-[RCTBatchedBridge loadSource:]_block_invoke(), /Users/spencerpope/Tutor2/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBatchedBridge.m:204
2015-12-02 11:50:11.274 TutorMeNow[81429:1527409] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'It looks like the implementationof __DEV__ has changed. Update -[RCTBatchedBridge loadSource:].'
  *** First throw call stack:
 (
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102574f45  __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101776deb     objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102574daa +   [NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
3   Foundation                          0x00000001013c36b2 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 169
4   TutorMeNow                          0x000000010038ad3d __31-[RCTBatchedBridge loadSource:]_block_invoke + 861
5   TutorMeNow                          0x00000001003723e3 __50+[RCTJavaScriptLoader loadBundleAtURL:onComplete:]_block_invoke + 195
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104e84e5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104ea549b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104e8dbef _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1829
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104e8d4c5 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001051d64f2 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001051d4375 start_wqthread + 13
 )
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
 (lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update packager url to http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true in AppDelegate (iOS).

Comment: Thats what the URL currently is.

Comment: @SpencerPope adding platform=ios&dev=true  to the url fix issue for me. If your url containe this options have not idea. Have you try to run from the pre bundled js code? is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Following the upgrade guide, "Manual Changes" section resolved this issue for me: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

There's a new Run Script phase that needs to be added:
[image]

[image]

Then main.jsbundle file needs to be deleted:
[image]

main.jsbundle is no longer necessary. Pick your device as target in XCode and hit the run button to deploy/run on device.